# How to Adjust Audio shape properties in animation timeline without messing with other animations?

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

In a PowerPoint VBA project I have to add an audio shape to a slide, position it on the first animation position so that it plays as a narration.
When I try to set the property StopAfterSlides = 1, the other animations in the timeline are affected, which is undesired.

Here you find a screenshot [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4dUv.png) changing the audio property from 0 to 1 and then a screenshot [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxgUq.png) the property change.

and here the code itself.

```
Set oAudio = lpSlide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(FileName:=lpAudioFile.Path, _
                                            LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                            SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                            Left:=0, _
                                            Top:=SlideHeight)
'Set audio shape properties
With oAudio
    .Height = CstAudioShapeHeight
    .Width = CstAudioShapeWidth
    .Name = CstAudioShapeName
    .Tags.Add Name:=CstAudioShapeTag, Value:="1"
End With

'Remove shape from the interactive timeline
lpSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences(1).Item(1).Delete

'Add shape effect to main timeline

Set oEffect = lpSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=oAudio, _
                                                        effectId:=msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, _
                                                        Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
'Set shape properties
With oEffect
.MoveTo 1
.EffectInformation.PlaySettings.StopAfterSlides = 1 **before** 'HERE COMES THE PROBLEM
End With
```

I appreciate any contribution!